# Join a domain without adopting group policy... through registry permissions?

Tags: domain, group-policy

As a local machine admin, is it possible to join a domain but still block group policy from being applied? I'm thinking it should be possible to remove all write access to the registry under, for example, `HKCU\Software\Policies` but in practice not sure how well this would work, or if there is already a better way to do so.

Let it be very clear: I am not interested in answers from the AD admin perspective, and even less interested in subjective answers of a self-righteous nature.

Comment: Guessing you're not an administrator of the domain and are trying to circumvent your appointed administrators security configuration. It's very simple for a domain admin to setup a machine on the domain and block group policy for it. So assuming you have a business case for that, just ask him/her.

Comment: As sysadmins, we take security seriously. GPOs are an important way ot accomplishing this. I'm afraid you won't get much help in circumventing security policies here.

Comment: No I'm not the adminsitrator of a domain, but the business case has been ignored. The situation is that the company I work for has been bought out and over November our machines are being migrated onto the parent company's domain. This has already caused problems with overzealous things like for example forced folder redirection preventing explorer from launching, and when the case was put forth that we need machines excluded the only solution offered was to allow us to keep local admin rights on our machines... but that's really not a fix.

Comment: Why is this question tagged "off-topic"? What is off-topic about it, specifically? This looks more like gate-keeping by system administrator majority, applied wrong.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want certain policies applied to a machine then you should use the existing filtering options for GPOs. Trying to hack your way around the way the system works is not the correct way to achieve what you want.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question, rather tries to shut it down. I'm specifically asking from a client machine perspective, not from domain admin.

Comment: @FerretallicA: We have a very strong culture of "Do it right or not at all". What you want to do is both doing it wrong and trying to circumvent policies imposed on you by the higher ups, which also isn't welcome here. Talk to the domain admins to apply filters to fix your  issues (which can't be all that bad if they still exist after nearly 5 years).

Comment: Regardless, it's not an answer. It's a comment at best.

Answer (score 3):

If you take permissions away from the SYSTEM account in HKLM, prepare for unexpected behavior if not outright failure. Filtering, as suggested, is the better way to go. There is also the possibility of making an OU for this machine that doesn't have any policies in it. A third option is to make a group full of computers that you want a certain policy to apply to. You then assign the policy to that group and any computers in the same OU that aren't a part of that group don't get the policy.